# (Bug?) InnoDB MySQL error 1025, errno 150 Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table whose primary key I'm trying to change.
this is the table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_customer` (
  `PersonId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) collate utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `Alias` varchar(50) collate utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(30) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `Phone2` varchar(30) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `Email2` varchar(50) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `RFC` varchar(13) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `AddressStreetName` varchar(45) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `AddressStreetNumber` varchar(45) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `AddressCityWard` varchar(45) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `AddressCityName` varchar(45) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `AddressStateName` varchar(45) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `AddressCountryName` varchar(45) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
  `AddressPostalCode` int(10) default NULL,
  `IsDistributor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT '1 = Is Distributor, 0 = Is Not Distributor',
  `ParentCustomerId` int(10) NOT NULL default '11' COMMENT 'Our Id is 11, so by default, all customers right now are our children.',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`),
  KEY `fk_tbl_cliente_tbl_cliente1_idx` (`ParentCustomerId`),
  KEY `fk_tbl_cliente_tbl_person1_idx` (`PersonId`),
  KEY `PersonId` (`PersonId`),
  KEY `PersonId_2` (`PersonId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_cliente_tbl_cliente1` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentCustomerId`) REFERENCES `tbl_customer` (`PersonId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_cliente_tbl_person1` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonId`) REFERENCES `zapata`.`tbl_person` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci COMMENT='''Customer'' refers to a person or entity to which we provide '$$
```

Now, when I first tried to:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_customer` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

My `PRIMARY KEY` is `Id` . When I tried to drop it I got..

```
Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of './services/#sql-29a_218cc7f' to './services/tbl_customer' (errno: 150)
```

So, I deleted all `FOREIGN KEY` constraints that referred to this table and column, and still got the same error. I also went over to `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` And found out this:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
130226 14:41:11 Error in foreign key constraint of table services/tbl_employee_shift:
there is no index in referenced table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
referenced table do not match to the ones in table. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT fk_tbl_employee_shift_tbl_customer1 FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES services.tbl_customer (Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

However, the table `services.tbl_employee_shift` does not exist (it existed once but it was dropped several weeks before I tried this change). So I went on and...

```
CREATE TABLE services.tbl_employee_shift(
    CustomerId INT (11)
);
ALTER TABLE services.tbl_employee_shift ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tbl_employee_shift_tbl_customer1 FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES avatar.tbl_cliente (Id);
ALTER TABLE services.tbl_employee_shift DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_tbl_employee_shift_tbl_customer1;
```

And it works... but it doesn't correct the necessary information, seemingly InnoDB still believes that the constraint `fk_tbl_employee_shift_tbl_customer1` is alive and thus, is 'preventing the drop of the primary key to keep consistency'...
I'm using MySQL 5.0.95.

EDIT: This problem went unresolved, it was worked around

The problem could only be corrected when we migrated the database to a newer server (same mysql version), seems like there was a broken/ghost reference to a ghost foreign key (fk_tbl_employee_shift_tbl_customer1 ) which prevented the column from being dropped. Since this broken/ghostfk wasn't in the new server, I could drop the column with no problems then. My guess is it was a bug, but unfortunately I can't recreate it.

Comment: When tbl_employee_shift table was dropped ? Before or after trying to drop tbl_customer's primary key ?

Comment: tbl_employee_shift was dropped several weeks before trying to change tbl_customer's primary key..

Comment: tbl_person is created with the innnoDB storage engine. Please review my SQL if you think it is incorrect. It is correct as far as I know. This seems like completely unexpected behavior because the PK cannot be dropped due to the FK referencing it, but the reference was previously dropped. Even if so, the same exact FK can be recreated and redropped. And after this is done, the reference still prevents the PK from being dropped...

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same problem, except I can't recreate the table with the foreign key. I get an errno 121 when I try! Unbelievable

Comment: @sudol Sorry for the delay, actually this went unresolved and the problem could only be corrected when we migrated to a newer server, seems like there was a broken reference to a ghost foreign key (fk_tbl_employee_shift_tbl_customer1 ) which prevented the column from being dropped. Since this ghost fk wasn't in the new server, I could drop the column with no problems then.

Comment: @Snivs Thanks for writing back. That's a shame. I could not find a good answer either. I worked around the problem by doing a mysqldump, then loading it right back in.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as though you dropped `tbl_employee_shift` whilst [`foreign_key_checks`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) was set to 0:

> Setting [`foreign_key_checks`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) to 0 also affects data definition statements: [`DROP SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/drop-database.html) drops a schema even if it contains tables that have foreign keys that are referred to by tables outside the schema, and [`DROP TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/drop-table.html) drops tables that have foreign keys that are referred to by other tables.

Since this behaviour is documented, it must be considered by-design and therefore not a bug.

Comment: It makes sense! ... but even if so, why does it allow me to recreate and drop both the table and the foreign key while having foreign_key_checks set to 1? Edit: Also, when I drop the recreated fk, the reference is still considered existing by InnoDB..

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when foreign key is bad formulated.
the SQL is correct, i run script in my localhost, i get same error.
the solution is verify  that table tbl_person was created with engine "InnoDB".

greetings

Comment: tbl_person is created with the innnoDB storage engine. Please review my SQL if you think it is incorrect. It is correct as far as I know. This seems like completely unexpected behavior because the PK cannot be dropped due to the FK referencing it, but the reference was previously dropped. Even if so, the same exact FK can be recreated and redropped. And after this is done, the reference still prevents the PK from being dropped...

Comment: me get same error, i solved  alter table tbl_person that was created with myisam. the diference between your tables and mine is that table tbl_person is in same database with  tbl_customer. i was hoping  this help you. sorry for  my english

Comment: Thanks, Chenio, but these tables are really dynamic and can't change to Myisam, guess I'll have to plan how to recreate the whole database during a scheduled maintenance, maybe so I can also recreate the InnoDB internal catalog... without that zombie FK

Answer (score 0):

Just dealt with this problem today. There was no sign of the two affected tables in any of the schema information tables. I searched the various system databases looking for the FK, to no avail. In the end, **dropping the database worked instantly.**

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error, what mysql requires is that you have both key and foreign, type and size match,
for eg. person.id int (10) must mapped to  service_customer.person_id in (10)
if the type and size differ, mysql will complain.

Comment: Unrelated, the FK was dropped, but it is still considered as existing.. and it's not MySQL, it's the InnoDB Storage engine.