# How do I delete a foreign key that does not exist from a table that does not exist, in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to rename a primary key in an InnoDB table and I kept getting an Errno 150. SHOW INNODB STATUS shows:

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
130711 18:22:53 Error in foreign key constraint of table xx/client_location_business_load:
there is no index in referenced table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
referenced table do not match the ones in table. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT "business_load_business_load_name_key" FOREIGN KEY ("name_id") REFERENCES "client_businesstype_load_name" ("name_id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The table `client_location_business_load` does not even exist! It was renamed. The constraint named `business_load_business_load_name_key` does not exist either, it was dropped and it does not appear in `information_schema.key_column_usage`.

Does anyone have a clue about what's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Bug?) InnoDB MySQL error 1025, errno 150 Foreign Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100545/bug-innodb-mysql-error-1025-errno-150-foreign-key)

Comment: I guess it looks like close to the same problem, but that question still doesn't have an answer and I'm not able to recreate the table in question since mysql thinks there is already a foreign key with that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to drop the database and recreate it in the same collation. There does not seem to be an alternative.